# Cloud Firestore with python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I want to use python and firebase but I want to use cloud firestore but I can not find way to do it can help me in this thank you very much.

Comment: The documentation has samples for all supported platforms, including Python: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart. If you're having trouble getting that to work, edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ GOMES0802, did you try the quickstart?

Answer (score 1):

Start by installing firebase-admin https://pypi.org/project/firebase-admin/ and following the tutorial from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart. You can fully control your Firestore DB with the python admin SDK.